# Sentry Multiple Groups Assignment

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I want to assign multiple groups to a user using sentry, how can I accomplish that?

I have a group table having id, name and permissions columns.

```
$groups = Sentry::findGroupById(1); anyway I can get multiple groups and then assign 

$groups while creating user $user = Sentry::register([ 'permisions' => $groups]);
```

Comment: I am not able to get multiple groups using sentry.
$groups = Sentry::findGroupById(1);
anyway I can get multiple groups and then assign $groups while creating user
$user = Sentry::register([ 'permisions' => $groups]);

Comment: this is a good reference which was never answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554367/sentry-multiple-permission-groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution

```php
foreach ($group as $g) {
    $addGroup= Sentry::findGroupById($g);
    $user->addGroup($addGroup);
}
```